# Failed to add the foreign key constraint in popsql

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

> Error: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'userid' for constraint 'buyer_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'users'

> Error: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'userid' for constraint 'seller_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'users'

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    user_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    phoneNo VARCHAR(20)
);
DESCRIBE Users;

CREATE TABLE Buyer
(
    userid INT NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY(userid)
    ,FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES Users(userid)
);

CREATE TABLE Seller
(
    userid INT NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY(userid)
    ,FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES Users(userid)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests `users` table has a column called `userid`, but the table DDL schema specify the column as `user_id` instead of `userid` (there is a '_' between user and Id). If that naming is intended, use the following query for foreign key creation:

```
CREATE TABLE Users( user_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), phoneNo VARCHAR(20) ); 

CREATE TABLE Buyer ( userid INT NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY(userid) ,FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES Users(user_id) );

CREATE TABLE Seller ( userid INT NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY(userid) ,FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES Users(user_id) );
```

Verified the DDL build are successful in [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vgYZoXhJQFS9CM4uDkNhmS/0)